# Nt4.0 Printer Driver not compatible with Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, printer

I've got a Brother Fax-8360P printer that has a standard printer port so it can be connected to my WindowsXP machine.  I've found some drivers on the net that work and it is a pretty decent laser printer.

However, when I try and connect up to it from my Vista machine over the network, it tells me that "The printer driver is not compatible with a policy enabled on your computer that blocks NT4.0 drivers".

Main question - is it possible to alter this so that my Vista machine will allow me to print via the network.

Secondary question - does anyone know of any generic driver that will work instead?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft support article [KB 931719](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931719).

Another [reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistasecurity/thread/24e64fe2-8b9e-4277-8ad7-c05e6bf0646d/)

> Please try on your VISTA machine:
>   Control Panel -> Printers -> Add a printer -> Add a local printer ->
>   Create a new port: Local Port ->
>   Enter a port name: \Your_XP_machine\Shared_Printer   [REPLACE W/ YOUR INFO]
>   Pick appropriate driver from list provided by Vista [Lexmark 4800]

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but the only driver I have for the printer is a kernel mode driver and Vista refuses to install it and the actual printer isn't on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend hunting down some generic PCL4 drivers and see if they work, a lot of brother devices are compatible with PCL.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it didn't want to talk to the printer (The printer received the data but didn't print).  I suspect as it is a Fax rather than a printer and someone cobbled together some drivers which aren't official ones.

Answer (score 1):

One policy in Windows Vista should be changed to enable the installation of old print drivers as menthioned in this site http://www.sysprobs.com/nt-40-printer-driver-compatible-policy-enabled-vista-pc
its working ok

Comment: This article also says: "Be prepared to receive Blue screen error on your Vista computer after this policy enabled."