# Can't install shared printer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

My printer is an Epson Stylus C60, which I use on a Windows XP desktop. I am trying to install the printer on a networked Windows 7 laptop - there are no printer drivers available from Epson who state I should use the built-in Windows 7 driver.

When the printer is connected to the laptop directly, the driver works. However once the printer is accessed again via the network, an error is shown on the laptop that the "driver cannot be found on the network", and I have to locate the correct driver. Is there a way to find the location of the driver on the laptop? And how can I successfully get the printer working on the network on my Windows 7 laptop?

Comment: this looks very much like a duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/62155/windows7-access-to-printer-shared-with-xp ... does that answer solve your problem?

Comment: I have rewritten this question to merge in some information provided in a (non) answer below. Noted that this question is quite old though...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about Windows7, but could your version have limited support for network printing?

When the printer is connected to XP and shared on the network, you should on the Win7 laptop go to:

Control Panel->Add a printer->Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer->The printer that I want isn't listed->Select a shared printer by name.

Enter "`\\xp-machine-name\printername`" in the box, and continue from there.